# Odoo : Acces payments_widget from database

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, computed-field

When you add a `widget="payment"` like in facturation module in Odoo, you get this (next to the red arrow).

[image]

How can you acces the values in this widget from the database? (From dev mode, it's said the field is payments_widget of account_invoice, which does not exist in database).

In my case, I just wanted to modify all the occurence of a value of a payment, by modifying the the database, (error during an entry I have to correct after the validation).

According to [this post](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-to-add-details-in-information-tab-pament-widget-in-odoo-10-119992), it's just a computed field. Then it should not be stored in the databse.

But after changing every other occurence of my amount in the database, the amount in the widget didn't change.

So why is that data persistent and where can it be found in database?

Answer (score 0):

This is something which has plagued me for quite some time, as well, due to incorrect currency conversion or tax rounding issues.  After some digging and a bit of testing, here is what worked for me, and I hope it works for you and anyone else plagued with the same or similar issue.

The payments widget accesses the `account.move` model.  As such, the values are not exactly stored in such a manner where you simply change one value to correct the issue.

Surprisingly, to change this one value, four records within the `account_move_line` table need to be modified.  Two of the records will be identifiable by the `invoice number` and the other two by the `invoice id`.

```
SELECT * FROM account_move_line
    WHERE ref = 'FAC/2018/0002'
    OR invoice_id = (
        SELECT id FROM account_invoice
            WHERE number = 'FAC/2018/0002'
    );
```

That should list the four records in question.  The values requiring update are the following:

- `credit_cash_basis`
- `debit`
- `debit_cash_basis`
- `credit`
- `balance_cash_basis`
- `amount_currency`
- `balance`

For each line with a credit value, there will be a corresponding entry with a debit value.  This is for account reconciliation.  Keep negative values negative and positive values positive.  All execpt `amount_currency` are in your company's primary currency, while `amount_currency` is the value in your partner's currency.

All of this is of course in addition to correcting the corresponding values in the `account.payment` model.